# Make goal depend on same prerequisite with different flags

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, gnu

I am trying to make a self-contained Makefile.
My Makefile has a rule like the following one:

```
benchmark:
      (something that depends on variable CXX)
```

That rule represents a single benchmark for a single compiler. I want to benchmark several compilers.

So what I would like to accomplish is the following without invoking `$(MAKE)` recursively from inside the plot rule (pseudo-syntax):

```
plot: benchmark CXX=clang++ benchmark CXX=g++
    (generate a plot)
```

Namely, I want this goal to depend on the prerequisite benchmark + one flag and treat both as two different prerequisites, even if they are the same rule.

Comment: Why are you against recursive invocation?  How do you plan to ensure that the object files are all rebuilt each time with the correct compiler, as well as the program linked with it?  I think you're headed in the wrong direction, but I'm not sure quite how to send you in the right direction.  Maybe you need a `benchmark-1` (sub-)directory where you build the executable for `g++` and a `benchmark-2` (sub-directory) where you build the executable for `clang++`.  The source can come from the original (parent) directory — maybe via VPATH.  But I've not tried that. _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ What I normally do is `make clean; make benchmark CXX=g++; make clean; make benchmark CXX=g++; make clean` or something similar.  The final `make clean` ensures that the next build behaves correctly, regardless of the sequence or success of the prior operations.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming GNU Make, I think the logic you're looking for can be expressed in this way:

```
CXXES := clang++ g++

benchmark: $(CXXES:%=benchmark-%)
```

Then have a single rule to generate the benchmarks:

```
benchmark-%:
    # generate a plot using $(CXX), which will be equal to $@
```

or multiple ones if your plot generation rules are compiler specific:

```
benchmark-clang++: CXX = clang++
    # generate a plot using $(CXX)
    (...)

benchmark-g++: CXX = g++
    # generate a plot using $(CXX)
    (...)
```

It would be better to identify output files (plots?) whose file names depend on the value of `$(CXX)` and use those as intermediate targets.

Comment: How is the dependency line supposed to work?  Won't they mean that `make` tries to make files `CXX`, `=`, and either `clang++` or `g++`, and probably fail?  You may be onto a germ of an idea — separately named targets that build the executable using different compilers.  But the object files would need to be renamed too.  I have a feeling it gets hairy.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: I haven't actually tried this, but the idea it to specify targets with specific `$(CXX)` values in their names, and have the overarching (phony) target depend on all of them. That idea should work, even if the details of this particular implementation turn out not to (in which case this answer should be fixed).

Comment: The problem is that those are two compilers. I cannot rely on a static rule like that. The rule must be something like benchmark-${COMPILER}

Comment: Why is that a problem? If the names of the compilers are variable, make variables for them and use them. If you don't even know how many compilers will be used in the first place, you'd need to generate the compiler-specific rules using an `include`d make file or `$(eval)`.

Comment: Is there anything compiler-specific about your compiler-specific rules, except the name of the compiler? If not, you don't need specific rules per compiler, you can just use pattern rules or rules with targets that include a variable holding the compiler name (or a variable whose value you derive from it). I just edited the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by [reinierpost](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17945/reinierpost) you can define a pseudo target for each of your compilers. A pseudo-target is a target that has no real file production associated with it.

But as make is really happy with real file targets (targets are considered up-to-date or not based on their last modification date) you could also use your plot result as a target. And, as also suggested, you could wrap all this in a `foreach`-`eval`-`call` construct to factorize your code. Something like:

```
COMPILERS = clang++ g++

define PLOT_compiler
plotfile-$(1): CXX = $(1)
plotfiles += plotfile-$(1)
endef

$(foreach compiler,$(COMPILERS),$(eval $(call PLOT_compiler,$(compiler))))

all: $(plotfiles)

plotfile-%:
    <generate plot file using the CXX variable>
```

The `foreach`-`eval`-`call` construct instantiates one set of make statements per compiler, as defined by the `PLOT_compiler` variable.

If you prefer collecting all results in a single file named, let's say, `plots.txt` you can instead use:

```
COMPILERS = clang++ g++

define PLOT_compiler
plotfile-$(1): CXX = $(1)
plotfiles += plotfile-$(1)
endef

$(foreach compiler,$(COMPILERS),$(eval $(call PLOT_compiler,$(compiler))))

plots.txt: $(plotfiles)
    cat $(plotfiles) > $@

plotfile-%:
    <generate plot file using the CXX variable>

clean:
    rm -f $(plotfiles)

ultraclean:
    rm -f $(plotfiles) plots.txt
```

The `clean` and `ultraclean` targets will help you keeping your workspace clean. You can easily test all this by replacing the `<generate plot file using the CXX variable>` recipe by `echo $(CXX) > $@`, and:

```
make
make clean
cat plots.txt
```

Comment: I want a single plot for all results :) It is divided in sections, per compiler. Compares two binaries for each compiler. So this does not match what I want. I thought that maybe this is not even consistent: I have something like CXX, which always works per compiler. But the result I want requires to compile several times. So I end up having a kind of "conflict" where for plotting the files I need to compile for different CXX but I only want a single plot file.

Comment: This is not a real problem. If you know how to add a new section to your existing plot file, you can use empty files as targets. Simply end your recipe with `touch $@` and you are done.